# Sonar and MAVEN POM file with Dependencies

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, sonarqube, maven-assembly-plugin

I have setup Maven and Sonar to analyze .NET projects and it works fine for winforms projects. However when I add an MVC project it gives a build Failure because it can't find the System.Web.MVC.dll file. I have an Fx-Cop plugin that runs as part of Sonar.
One way to get around this would be to package the dll, copy local= true with the project. However I dont want to do that(any thing wrong with packaging the MVC file along?)

*How do I add a dependency to the MVC dll?* I followed [this example](http://incubator.apache.org/npanday/docs/1.4.0-incubating/guide/vs/references.html) and added it like this:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>artifact_group_id</groupId>
    <artifactId>System.WEb.MVC</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.30319</version>
    <type>library</type>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>C:\DOTNET\DLLS\System.Web.Mvc.dll</systemPath>
  </dependency>   
</dependencies>
```

*Still I get a Build Failure caused by FX-Cop*. Looking at the FX-Cop logs I get a message as below:

> The following error was encountered while reading module 'MyTestMvcApp': Assembly reference cannot be resolved: System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.

I'm using apache-maven-3.0.2 and sonar-3.2. Can anyone help with this?

This is the full POM.XML file

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">


  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Sonar.For.NET.Test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>Testing </name>
  <packaging>netpack</packaging>

  <properties>
    <visual.studio.solution>TestProjectsForSonarBuild.sln</visual.studio.solution>
    <visual.test.project.pattern>*.Tests;*Test</visual.test.project.pattern>
    <dotnet.tool.version>4.0</dotnet.tool.version>
    <sonar.language>cs</sonar.language>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>artifact_group_id</groupId>
     <artifactId>System.WEb.MVC</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.30319</version>
     <type>library</type>
     <scope>system</scope>
     <systemPath>C:\DOTNET\DLLS\System.Web.Mvc.dll</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies> 


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.dotnet</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dotnet-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.6</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
                <toolVersion>3.5</toolVersion>
                <buildConfigurations>Debug</buildConfigurations>
                <rebuild>true</rebuild>
            <language>cs</language>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "sonar.fxcop.assemblyDependencyDirectories" property as described on [the documentation page for the FxCop plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/sonar-csharp-fxcop-plugin).

So you have 2 solutions from there:

- either your build process copies "System.Web.MVC.dll" in a temp folder, which you reference through the this property
- or you directly reference an absolute path where this DLL can be found (but your property may then be not portable accros different environments/servers)